# NotFoundPage returned

Tags: reactjs, react-router, enzyme, jestjs

I try to test my `AppRouter` component with Jest and Enzyme :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';

import AppRouter from './../src/components/AppRouter';
import Home from './../src/components/Home';
import NotFoundPage from './../src/components/NotFoundPage';

describe('App Router', () => {
  it('should go to 404 page', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[ '/random' ]}>
        <AppRouter />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(wrapper.contains(<Home />)).toBe(false);
    expect(wrapper.contains(<NotFoundPage />)).toBe(true);
  })
})
```

This is my `AppRouter` component :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Home';
import NotFoundPage from './NotFoundPage';

const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

and this is the test log :

```
● App Router › should go to 404 page

    expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using Object.is):
      true
    Received:
      false

      15 |     console.log(wrapper.contains(<AppRouter />));
      16 |     expect(wrapper.contains(<Home />)).toBe(false);
    > 17 |     expect(wrapper.contains(<NotFoundPage />)).toBe(true);
      18 |   })
      19 | })
      20 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/appRouter.test.js:17:91)
```

With the `initialEntries={[ '/random' ]}` I have to get a `NotFoundPage`.

Any idea ?

Comment: Try adding `<MemoryRouter initialEntries={[ '/random' ]} initialIndex={0} >`

Comment: This still not working. I think it's because I am trying to take find a React Component and I can only find a DOM element. 

This is working when I do a find by className (add it after the post) to have length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as I had expected, it's a misunderstanding. It works with the code below :

Entry point component :

```
/* global document */
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import AppRouter from './components/AppRouter';

render(
  <Router>
    <AppRouter />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

AppRouter Component :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Home';
import World from './World';
import NotFoundPage from './NotFoundPage';

const AppRouter = () => (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/world" component={World} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

AppRouter Test :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import AppRouter from './../src/components/AppRouter';
import Home from './../src/components/Home';
import World from './../src/components/World';
import NotFoundPage from './../src/components/NotFoundPage';

describe('App Router', () => {
  it('should go to 404 page', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[ '/random' ]} initialIndex={0}>
        <AppRouter />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    expect(wrapper.find(NotFoundPage)).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find(Home)).toHaveLength(0);
    expect(wrapper.find(World)).toHaveLength(0);
  });

  it('should go to world page', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[ '/world' ]} initialIndex={0}>
        <AppRouter />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    expect(wrapper.find(Home)).toHaveLength(0);
    expect(wrapper.find(World)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
})
```

For test the routes of your application you have to use MemoryRouter for emulate the BrowserRouter of react-router-dom.

But you have to be careful to treat only with the routes and not with the BrowserRouter in the component to test.